# Is it OK to route under small mosfet transistor?

Tags: transistors, pcb-design, emc, layout, esd

I have a 2-layer board where I am thinking of routing TX and RX to microcontroller under a small P-channel mosfet.

I know some parts can be considered sensitive and one should not route under them.

Is a small mosfet one one of these parts that one should not route under?

[image: imgage]

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with going under the mosfet, but make sure your trace to pad clearances are OK. NetR17_2 looks awfully close to the VCC pad. I avoid going between pads on a SOT-23 when possible. But sometimes you have to. I don't think I have ever routed two traces under a SOT-23, though.

Answer (score 3):

I've had trouble where the soldermask opening on the corner of the pad would be a little bit too wide so when soldering components it would short to the trace. This isn't detected by board electrical testing since the short happens when soldering.

[image]

If you trust the manufacturer to be able to manufacture according to their tolerances, and if the tolerances allow it, then why not, but I'd still trust the clearance between tracks more than clearance between track and pad. So I'd move stuff around to get minimum clearance between tracks, and a bit more clearance to the pads. That way it leaves more space for soldermask to be a bit off. Especially on the top half of the picture, you can do that for "free" by moving both tracks to the right.

You could also put 45° corners or round corners on these pads.

If this is a hobby project, the small extra cost of 4 layers from shops like jlcpcb is definitely worth it, just think about how many hours it saves...

Comment: OK, thank you for your feedback =)